# Get global keyboard input with Java

Tags: java, low-level, keyboard-hook

How can I get what is being inputed in any program outside my java program.. Is there a way ?
For example, I'm running my java program then I start typing in notepad, and I can see with my java program what is being typed.

Answer (score 2):

The term you should looking for is **Keyboard hooks**, here is example using WinApi http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/keyboardhook.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in pure Java.  At some point, it will involve talking to an external application or a native library, and will be platform specific in either case.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library to handle native keyboard and mouse control:
http://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/